# rails, How to build table in helper using content_tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I defined function in application helper:

```
def display_standard_table(columns, collection = {})    
  content_tag :table do      
    concat content_tag :thead do
      content_tag :tr do
        concat columns.collect { |column| content_tag(:td, column[:display_name]) }
      end
    end      

    concat content_tag :tbody do
      collection.collect { |elem| 
        concat content_tag(:tr, columns.collect { |column|
          content_tag(:td, elem.attributes[column[:name]])
      })
    }
    end
  end
end
```

and I call it in my view:

```
<%= display_standard_table(
          [
            { :name => 'id', :display_name => 'Id' },
            { :name => 'login', :display_name => 'Login' },
            { :name => 'first_name', :display_name => 'Name' },
            { :name => 'last_name', :display_name => 'LastName' },
            { :name => 'email', :display_name => 'Email'}
          ], @users) %>
```

The output in html is:

```
<table><thead></thead><tbody></tbody></table>
```

and it should be:

```
<table><thead><tr><td>Id</td><td>Login</td>...</tr></thead><tbody><tr>row here</tr></tbody></table>
```

and i can't figure out what's missing. (btw. I'm using rails3)

[EDIT]

```
def display_standard_table(columns, collection = {})    
  content_tag(:table) do
    concat(content_tag(:thead) do
      concat(content_tag(:tr) do
        concat(columns.collect { |column| content_tag(:td, column[:display_name]) })
      end)
    end)

    concat(content_tag(:tbody) do
      concat(collection.collect { |elem|
        content_tag(:tr, columns.collect { |column|
          content_tag(:td, elem.attributes[column[:name]])
        })
      })
    end)
  end
end
```

The above version works ok but generated html is escaped :/ according to documentation strings produced by content_tag should be html_safe, but they're escaped :/

Answer (score 37):

```
def display_standard_table(columns, collection = {})

 thead = content_tag :thead do
   content_tag :tr do
    columns.collect {|column|  concat content_tag(:th,column[:display_name])}.join().html_safe
   end
 end

 tbody = content_tag :tbody do
  collection.collect { |elem|
    content_tag :tr do
      columns.collect { |column|
          concat content_tag(:td, elem.attributes[column[:name]])
      }.to_s.html_safe
    end

  }.join().html_safe
 end

 content_tag :table, thead.concat(tbody)

end
```

Answer (score 5):

Actually you are only missing a plus between content tags, you can find a similar question here

[Rails- nested content_tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205613/rails-nested-content-tag)

The problem with this, is that maybe you will get a syntax error because of the way you are using the blocks, if you use a "{}" instead of "do end" statements you are going to be Ok.

Here ([Change to the way the block is handled](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper/content_tag#1111-Change-to-the-way-the-block-is-handled)) you can find an example and a workaround in the case you use Rails 3 because apparently Rails 3 ignore the result of the collect statement when is inside of the content tag.

Answer (score 1):

See the railscast about that : http://railscasts.com/episodes/208-erb-blocks-in-rails-3 all is explain how you manage your block helper in rails 3

Answer (score 0):

It's the *missing* `concat` in your `:tr` related `content_tag`.

*Update*

As for the escaping, take a look at the [api docs for `content_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-content_tag). You need to specify not to escape it. Of course, you'd be responsible for escaping the stuff inside the tags that you want escaped in that case.

Comment: when i remove concat at all it gives me this: <table><tbody></tbody></table>

Answer (score 0):

Adding '.join().html_safe' to the end of each collect section. That's what worked for me.

```
  collection.collect { |elem| 
    concat content_tag(:tr, columns.collect { |column|
      content_tag(:td, elem.attributes[column[:name]])
  })
}.join().html_safe
```