# Rails- nested content_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, helper

I'm trying to nest content tags into a custom helper, to create something like this:

```
<div class="field">
   <label>A Label</label>
   <input class="medium new_value" size="20" type="text" name="value_name" />
</div>
```

Note that the input is not associated with a form, it will be saved via javascript.

Here is the helper (it will do more then just display the html):

```
module InputHelper
    def editable_input(label,name)
         content_tag :div, :class => "field" do
          content_tag :label,label
          text_field_tag name,'', :class => 'medium new_value'
         end
    end
end

<%= editable_input 'Year Founded', 'companyStartDate' %>
```

However, the label is not displayed when I call the helper, only the input is displayed.  If it comment out the text_field_tag, then the label is displayed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 163, accepted):

You need a `+` to quick fix :D

```
module InputHelper
  def editable_input(label,name)
    content_tag :div, :class => "field" do
      content_tag(:label,label) + # Note the + in this line
      text_field_tag(name,'', :class => 'medium new_value')
    end
  end
end

<%= editable_input 'Year Founded', 'companyStartDate' %>
```

Inside the block of `content_tag :div`, only the last returned string would be displayed.

Comment: Typo (in comment only, but slightly confusing) - "Not*e* the + in this line"

Comment: After adding that in, I get syntax error: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting kDO or '{' or '('
        text_field_tag name,'', :class => 'medium new_value'
                           ^

Comment: This feels dirty... is that because it's an anti-pattern for a helper to build multiple content tags?

Comment: Didn't work for me, had to use `concat` like the other answers suggest

Answer (score 60):

You can also use the [concat](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-concat) method:

```
module InputHelper
  def editable_input(label,name)
    content_tag :div, :class => "field" do
      concat(content_tag(:label,label))
      concat(text_field_tag(name,'', :class => 'medium new_value'))
    end
  end
end
```

Source: [Nesting content_tag in Rails 3](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/9123352587/nesting-content-tag-in-rails-3)

Comment: This worked for me as long as the concat line was on 1 line. I didn't spend long playing with it, though, so there's probably a way to do it multi-line

Comment: this will be a better way considering the html_safe issue. using `+` between non-htmlsafe string will make everything non-htmlsafe

Comment: If you are inside a form builder class, it should be `@template.concat`

Comment: I think it's a cleaner solution way to do than `+`. More readable and Rubocop doesn't like `+`

Answer (score 4):

I use a variable and concat to help with deeper nesting.

```
def billing_address customer
  state_line = content_tag :div do
    concat(
      content_tag(:span, customer.BillAddress_City) + ' ' +
      content_tag(:span, customer.BillAddress_State) + ' ' +
      content_tag(:span, customer.BillAddress_PostalCode)
    )
  end
  content_tag :div do
    concat(
      content_tag(:div, customer.BillAddress_Addr1) +
      content_tag(:div, customer.BillAddress_Addr2) +
      content_tag(:div, customer.BillAddress_Addr3) +
      content_tag(:div, customer.BillAddress_Addr4) +
      content_tag(:div, state_line) +
      content_tag(:div, customer.BillAddress_Country) +
      content_tag(:div, customer.BillAddress_Note)
    )
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

building nested content tags with iteration is a little different and gets me every time... here is one method:

```
      content_tag :div do
        friends.pluck(:firstname).map do |first| 
          concat( content_tag(:div, first, class: 'first') )
        end
      end
```