# RoR | how to get content_tags to nest?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

As you can see I have a helper with a method that I'm trying to render out to the view.

The nested content_tags do not render what is my disconnect about this tag?

```
def draw_calendar(selected_month, month, current_date)
  content_tag(:table) do

    content_tag(:thead) do

      content_tag(:tr) do

        I18n.t(:"date.abbr_day_names").map{ |day| content_tag(:th, day, :escape => false) }

      end #content_tag :tr
    end #content_tag :thead 

    content_tag(:tbody) do 

      month.collect do |week| 

        content_tag(:tr, :class => "week") do

          week.collect do |date| 

            content_tag(:td, :class => "day") do

              content_tag(:div, date.day, :class => (Date.today == current_date ? "today" : nil))

            end #content_tag :td
          end #week.collect
        end #content_tag :tr
      end #month.collect
    end #content_tag :tbody 
  end #content_tag :table
end #draw_calendar
```

::: EDIT :::

So here is what worked. Thanks again mu is too short!

```
def draw_calendar(selected_month, month, current_date)
  tags = []

  content_tag(:table) do

    tags << content_tag(:thead, content_tag(:tr, I18n.t("date.abbr_day_names").collect { |name| content_tag :th, name}.join.html_safe))

    tags << content_tag(:tbody) do 

      month.collect do |week| 

        content_tag(:tr, :class => "week") do

          week.collect do |date| 

            content_tag(:td, :class => "day") do

              content_tag(:div, :class => (Date.today == current_date ? "today" : nil)) do

                date.day.to_s

              end #content_tag :div
            end #content_tag :td
          end.join.html_safe #week.collect
        end #content_tag :tr
      end.join.html_safe #month.collect
    end #content_tag :tbody 
    tags.join.html_safe
  end #content_tag :table
end #draw_calendar
```

end

Comment: Similar to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205613/rails-nested-content-tag You missed an `+` (or anything) concatenating the `thead` and `tbody`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your problem is that [`content_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-content_tag) wants its block to return a string, you can trace through the code to see that it uses [`capture`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4f66586bbfacbce4c07f2b9d8d142be1bf6d4e5e/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb#L38) from `CaptureHelper` and that ignores any non-string return from the block.

You need to turn your `collect`s into strings with something like this:

```
content_tag(:tbody) do 
  month.collect do |week| 
    content_tag(:tr, :class => "week") do
      week.collect do |date|
        ..
      end.join.html_safe
    end
  end.join.html_safe
end
```

For example, a helper like this:

```
content_tag(:table) do
  content_tag(:thead) do
    content_tag(:tr) do
      [1,2,3,4].map do |i|
        content_tag(:td) do
          "pancakes #{i}"
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

produces:

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr></tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

but adding the `.join.html_safe`:

```
content_tag(:table) do
  content_tag(:thead) do
    content_tag(:tr) do
      [1,2,3,4].map do |i|
        content_tag(:td) do
          "pancakes #{i}"
        end
      end.join.html_safe
    end
  end
end
```

produces the expected:

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>pancakes 1</td>
            <td>pancakes 2</td>
            <td>pancakes 3</td>
            <td>pancakes 4</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this really helped better understand everything I was trying so hard to figure out. :) 2+ usefull

Comment: @DigitalCake: Unfortunately you end up becoming familiar with the Rails source or doing a lot of guesswork and experimentation if you want to do anything non-trivial with Rails. At least that's been my experience.