# Why does this nested content_tag not render properly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, helper

I have this in my helper:

```
  def favorites_count(node)
    content_tag :span, class: "card-favorite-count" do
      content_tag :i, class: "icon-heart"
      node.cached_votes_total
    end
  end
```

That is being called like this in the view:

```
<%= favorites_count(node) %>
```

And that renders this:

```
<span class="card-favorite-count"></span>
```

How do I get it to render the entire thing?

**Edit 1**

Per @tolgap's suggestion below, I tried this:

```
  def favorites_count(node)
    content_tag :span, class: "card-favorite-count" do
      content_tag(:i, "" ,class: "icon-heart") + node.cached_votes_total
    end
  end
```

But that doesn't output the number value in `node.cached_votes_total`. It outputs everything else though, and in the correct semantic order. It is just the final part of this doesn't work quite yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured out the answer. This is what the correct solution looks like:

```
  def favorites_count(node)
    content_tag :span, class: "card-favorite-count" do
      concat(content_tag(:i, "" ,class: "icon-heart"))
      concat(node.cached_votes_total)
    end
  end
```

Note that I had to use two `concat()` methods, because concat basically acts like a puts to the view. `content_tag` basically just returns the last line in the method to the view, so to override that I have to do that.

This comes from [this article](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/nesting-content-tag-in-rails-3) and this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15919046/91970).

Answer (score 3):

The last expression in the `do` block for a `content_tag` is what the content will be. So change it to:

```
def favorites_count(node)
  content_tag :span, class: "card-favorite-count" do
    node.cached_votes_total + content_tag(:i, class: "icon-heart")
  end
end
```

So you concatenate those two together. Of course, you will need to do `nil` checks on `node.cached_total_votes` now.

Comment: I got this error: `ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer can't be coerced into Fixnum` on that `node.cached_votes_total...` line.

Comment: Ok...I swapped them around. i.e. I did the `content_tag(:i, " ", class: "icon-heart") + node.cached_votes_total`. The issue is now I see the heart, but I don't see the content from `node.cached_votes_total`. In the HTML, it prints as `""`.