# rails ignoring content tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, helper, content-tag

I have the following code in one of my helpers:

```
  def send_fragments_to_other_template(template, counter)
    if counter == 0
      content_tag "div", class: "card w-5c" do
        content_tag "div", class: "card__content resource" do
          content_tag "h4" do
            content_tag "span", "Send fragments to other template"
          end
          link_to "Send", edit_admin_template_fragment_path(template), class: "btn btn--s-purple", remote: true
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

**Here's the problem**: for whatever reason, the third and fourth content tags are being ignored by rails. I have the two divs and the button (anchor), but not the h4 or the span, on the page.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks similar to this post on stack overflow: [Why does this nested content_tag not render properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31499458/why-does-this-nested-content-tag-not-render-properly)
What's happening here is that content_tag renders just the last expression from the do-end block. That's probably why you can see the "Send" button and not the others. 
I would prefer using concat, which behaves like puts, to get past this. It's the second answer in the post above^.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Sindhu! That answer was right, I needed a concat.
Thanks for pointing me to the right post, next time I'm going to search more before posting.